# Newline Character at the end of a .dat or .txt file?

Tags: c, vim

f1 = file pointer to a file, opened in read mode.
c = character variable.
`while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)`

when I try to read from a file(edited by vim), the "getc"  reads a newline character at the end of the file, thus I get a newline character in variable "c" and I am pretty sure that I did not write any "newline" character or any carriage return at the end of file. Why does my file has this "newline" character on its own.

Comment: This is the default behavior of Vim.

Comment: `c` should be an `int`

Comment: but I'm getting problem because of it, like I'm trying to check for a palindrome. So, when I read forward I get "newline" at the end but when I read backwards I get "newline" character at the start.. It just cant be checked for a palindrome.?? plz answer...

Comment: You can tweak your `.vimrc` to disable it.

Comment: You could also start your palindromic file with an empty line.

Answer (score 3):

@gmorrow (in the comments) is right that this is the default behavior, but I do not think that modifying your vimrc file is what you want to do.  While you are editing a file that should not end with a newline character, try

```
:set binary noendofline
:help 'binary'
:help 'eol'
```